# How to find status of criminal prosecution (Alberta, Canada)

Tags: criminal-law, canada, fraud, criminal-record, alberta

[Calgary men charged after 864 investors lose $33M in Crowsnest Pass development](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/calgary/real-estate-fraud-crownest-pass-charges-bridgecreek-development-corporation-1.3628985)
Jun 10, 2016

I can't find any further news about this. I tried contacting CBC but got no reply.
(Not to be confused with a related civil suit involving Becker and Bradley.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Alberta Investors Protection](http://www.albertainvestorsprotection.com/thread.php?tid=630)'s discussion forum:

> On September 13, 2019, Bradley pleads guilty to theft over $5,000 contrary to section 334(a) of the Criminal Code of Canada.  It’s a plea bargain: “Bradley wanted to save Mr. Becker from the possibility of incarceration.”
>
> Sometime in 2020, Bradley decides that he wants to revoke/expunge his guilty plea and go to trial anyway.
>
> On August 11, 2020, the Queen’s Bench Court throws out this latest BBoy attempt to avoid justice with the words: “The application to expunge is denied and his (Bradley’s) sentencing shall proceed accordingly.” [*Post dated 10/11/2020*]

And

> Bradley got 42 months. Becker charges were stayed. [*Post dated 22/03/2021*]

**Caveat**
This is the only current (i.e. December 2021) reference I can find and I've not been able to test the creditability or accuracy of this information as it lacks citations, and there is nothing relevant (that I can find) on the RCMP or news websites.

Comment: I found the [decision on the application to expunge](https://www.canlii.org/en/ab/abqb/doc/2020/2020abqb467/2020abqb467.html?resultIndex=6#document).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I would need to contact the courts as Matthew says.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you would need to contact the Calgary courts directly to discover more about the case(s) as any case files will likely be held with them. It's possible that the case was dropped, or that they were found "not guilty" which would explain the lack of further news on them.

I searched the [Canadian Legal Information Institute](https://www.canlii.org)'s website for you but wasn't able to find any criminal cases involving them — only some civil cases around bankruptcy and creditor claims.

Comment: Even a "dropped" (I assume you mean dismissed) case, or one which ended with a verdict of not guilty, would generate a case record. Court records can also be accessed via Lexis, available at Alberta public law libraries. I'd not surprised if access could also be had from other Canadian public law libraries.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that. I'm not sure why there aren't any case records for these fraud charges then.

Comment: I am perplexed as well. Both questions (what happened, and why we can't easily _know_ what happened) are interesting.